# HighCharts - Don't show line or change line style if date not reached

Tags: highcharts

We are using highcharts to display daily sales comparisons with past months.

[image]

The red line indicates the current week. Today is Wednesday and notice that the red line dives down to zero (I have highlighted that section in yellow), simply because Thursday has not arrived and so there are no sales yet. However, this has the appearance of a downward trend.

Is there a way to change the line to a different style for days that haven't arrived yet, e.g. a light grey dotted line, or even no line at all?

Comment: Can you setup demo example ? (http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: You can set the value to null instead of zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The chart only will display it's data, if you want to remove it you can pass `null` as it's value.
This way your chart range goes from Monday to Sunday, but the line will stop on Saturday.

[**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/ricardolohmann/s9qHH/)